# Element UploadAttachments is not a known element

Tags: web-controls, ascx, xaf

I am using Dev Express's xaf platform and want to add a .ascx web user control to my module.web project, so that I can use it as a WebCustomUserControlViewItem

I get the following error

[image]

There is no web.config in my module.web project because it is maintained by the main web project.

I did try creating one but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ascx control does not belong in the module project.  Create the controller in the .web project ( not module.web) and register it using

```
protected override DevExpress.ExpressApp.Core.ControllersManager CreateControllersManager()
    {
        DevExpress.ExpressApp.Core.ControllersManager result = base.CreateControllersManager();
        result.RegisterController(new Web.KgFileUploadController());
        return result;
    }
```

in WebApplication.cs